# brush not painting onto neither UV or live view model

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor, brushes

so I've been using Blender for quite a while now and made multiple models in the texture paint tab without many issues. This time it's causing me some confusion.

As I paint with stabilizing stroke & a constant fall-off, within this model file only the brush does not work. Neither in the UV unwrap viewport nor the live model does the brush not affect anything. I'm likely missing something incredibly obvious but I can't tell what. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated for this.

file: (hopefully I did the packing of materials right.)
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have loaded a texture for your brush, plus it's completely black, so just remove it and you'll be able to paint:

[image]

Comment: thank you so so much  it started to work again! i never knew the brush had a loaded image set in. i really appreciate your help!